# npm-install command not working in an angular 7 project

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

I downloaded a project from git, which is written in angular 7. I just need to run command npm install to run it. But its showing the following error.

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: ng-connection-monitor@0.0.0

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/abhiz/.npm/_logs/2019-04-24T07_30_14_888Z-debug.log
```

The following is a small part of the detailed error report from the log file(/home/abhiz/.npm/_logs/2019-04-24T07_30_14_888Z-debug.log).

```
    ... ... ...
    ... ... ...
    23 silly saveTree | `-- ssf@0.10.2
    23 silly saveTree |   `-- frac@1.1.2
    23 silly saveTree `-- zone.js@0.8.26
    24 verbose stack Error: 404 Not Found: ng-connection-monitor@0.0.0
    24 verbose stack     at fetch.then.res (/home/abhiz/.nvm/versions/node/v10.0.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/fetchers/registry/fetch.js:42:19)
    24 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (/home/abhiz/.nvm/versions/node/v10.0.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    24 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/abhiz/.nvm/versions/node/v10.0.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
    24 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (/home/abhiz/.nvm/versions/node/v10.0.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
    24 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/abhiz/.nvm/versions/node/v10.0.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
    24 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (/home/abhiz/.nvm/versions/node/v10.0.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)
    24 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueue (/home/abhiz/.nvm/versions/node/v10.0.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
    24 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueues (/home/abhiz/.nvm/versions/node/v10.0.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
    24 verbose stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/home/abhiz/.nvm/versions/node/v10.0.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
    24 verbose stack     at runCallback (timers.js:696:18)
    24 verbose stack     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:667:5)
    24 verbose stack     at processImmediate (timers.js:649:5)
    25 verbose cwd /home/abhiz/WorkSpace/TreadFormAnalysis
    26 verbose Linux 4.15.0-47-generic
    27 verbose argv "/home/abhiz/.nvm/versions/node/v10.0.0/bin/node" "/home/abhiz/.nvm/versions/node/v10.0.0/bin/npm" "install"
    28 verbose node v10.0.0
    29 verbose npm  v6.4.1
    30 error code E404
    31 error 404 Not Found: ng-connection-monitor@0.0.0
    32 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Only for this project npm install is not working. I have tried running this command in another angular 7 project and it run successfully.
 What is " ng-connection-monitor@0.0.0 " and how to resolve this error?

These informations may be needed.
My system's npm -version is 6.4.1 and node version is 10.0.In this project web socket is used.

Package.json file

```
        {
      "name": "app-demo",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
      },
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^6.1.3",
        "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.6",
        "@angular/common": "^6.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "^6.0.0",
        "@angular/forms": "^6.0.0",
        "@angular/http": "^6.0.0",
        "@angular/material": "^6.4.6",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.0",
        "@angular/router": "^6.0.0",
        "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^3.2.0",
        "@ngx-loading-bar/core": "^4.1.1",
        "@ngx-loading-bar/http-client": "^4.0.0",
        "angular-svg-round-progressbar": "^2.0.0",
        "angular2-cookie": "^1.2.6",
        "angular2-toaster": "^6.1.0",
        "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
        "core-js": "^2.5.4",
        "file-saver": "^2.0.0",
        "jquery": "^3.3.1",
        "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.11",
        "net": "1.0.2",
        "ng-connection-service": "^1.0.4",
        "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.1.4",
        "ngx-cookie-service": "^1.0.10",
        "ngx-spinner": "^6.1.2",
        "ngx-toggle-switch": "^2.0.5",
        "rxjs": "^6.2.2",
        "sockjs-client": "^1.3.0",
        "stompjs": "^2.3.3",
        "xlsx": "^0.14.1",
        "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.6.8",
        "@angular/cli": "~6.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.0",
        "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
        "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
        "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
        "karma": "^3.0.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
        "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "protractor": "^5.4.1",
        "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
        "tslint": "~5.9.1",
        "typescript": "~2.7.2",
        "net": "1.0.2",
        "angular-svg-round-progressbar": "2.0.0",
        "ng-connection-monitor": "0.0.0"
      }
    }
```

Comment: Are you behind proxy?

Comment: no. And this command is working in other angular projects

Comment: @Abhiz well npm install is installing your dependencies defined in the package.json file. Different projects have different dependencies. Here 1 of your dependencies are failing. Can you show your package.json file? - it is rather impossible to debug without. It tries to install version 0.0.0 of ng-connection-monitior - this seems pretty odd.

Comment: yes ,  sure. I ll edit my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the project you downloaded requires the `ng-connection-monitor` library as a build dependency and **npm was unable to find this library** when you did an `npm install`. Looking on [npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=ng-connection-monitor) for `ng-connection-monitor` returns no results so this would explain your `404` error:

> 404 Not Found: ng-connection-monitor@0.0.0

This leads me to believe that *this module is either a private package or has since been deleted off of npmjs*... so you will be unable to download this required build dependency as listed within your `package.json` file. Alternatively, there is however a `ng-connection-service` module listed on npmjs.

Perhaps you could proceed as follows:

Try *removing this dependency* from your `package.json` file and see if your project *still builds and works appropriately*. Alternatively, maybe try to *get in contact with the author of the GIT repo you've cloned* and see what the deal is with this module? As previously mentioned, this module may now be deprecated and has been replaced with another module so it was *removed off of npmjs* or it's a private module which isn't made publicly available on npmjs.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thanks for such a brief answer. It helped.

Comment: Glad it helped, please consider accepting my answer